# Moving Turtlebot 3 burger to few meters

Tags: python, turtlebot, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone. I am using turtlebot 3 burger with ros kinetic kame with ubuntu 16.04 in my PC. I am a beginner. I have successfully installed ros and i can move my robot using keyboard. Now i want to move robot to few meters by giving him a command. My question is that is there a specific python api with which i can do that. Or anyway else i can move my robot autonomously.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328569/moving-turtlebot-3-burger-to-few-meters/) by [enthusiast.australia](https://answers.ros.org/users/43404/enthusiast.australia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2019-07-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should have a look at the [ROS Navigation Stack](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation), that contains the components to implement a full autonomous navigation.

Among these packages, the one responsible for moving the robot is [MoveBase](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base).
This provides you API for moving the robot toward a goal. This goal could be computed in local coordinates and it could easily represent the concept of "X meters in front of the robot".
The "problem" is that you will also need a localization package in order to understand when the robot has really traveled that distance.
Something very simple could be dead reckoning, i.e. just looking at the wheel encoders.

The Navigation stack contains tutorial for setting up all what you need.

However, in an extremely oversimplified scenario, if you know that your robot moves at 1m/s you can create a function that publishes the "move forward command" that you are executing through the keyboard for the required amount of time to cover your distance.
This "command" will be a message of type `geometry_msgs/Twist` on topic `cmd_vel`.

EDIT:

I don't advise you to run something as "move randomly for 30 seconds" on a turtlebot, if you don't want to crash it against a wall.
Anyhow, you can do something like

```
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist

pub = rospy.Publisher('cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=10)
rospy.init_node('node_name')
r = rospy.Rate(30) # 30hz

total_time = 10 #seconds
start_time = time.time()

while not rospy.is_shutdown() or (time.time() - start_time < total_time):

    msg = Twist()
    
    # here you should fill the msg fields
    # http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Twist.html
    # you can fill it randomly or with a direction in mind

    pub.publish(msg)
    r.sleep()
```

---

Originally posted by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) with karma: 1322 on 2019-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [enthusiast.australia](https://answers.ros.org/users/43404/enthusiast.australia/) on 2019-07-16**:
Thanks alot for your help. Actually i am looking for a simplified thing. I have turtlebot. I have removed LiDAR sensor, now it is just pi3 and a micro controller. I just want to move robot with commands rather than keyboard. for example move 1 meter forward or may be to start random motion for 30 seconds.

**Comment by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on 2019-07-16**:
This is not an answer.
You should edit your initial post or comment my answer if you want to add details.
If you find my answer complete, mark it as accepted. Thanks